# AngularJS - acentos

Tags: angularjs, acentuação

Estou usando `AngularJS` e `Wamp Server`.

No programa que estou fazendo tenho um array:

```
($rootScope.fruits = ["banana","maça","laranja",'época'];)
```

Que está dando problemas nos acentos.
Aí fui colocar no *plunker* para mostrar o código e lá o acento funciona...

http://plnkr.co/edit/97iLW06tq1hcEdQymvA8?p=preview

Alguém sabe me dizer o que que eu faço para resolver isso na minha máquina?

Answer (score 3):

Deve ser a codificação do seu arquivo, tente mudar ela para utf-8.

Ou você pode adicionar direto no html dentro da tag head:

```
<head>
....
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
....
</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

Talvez seja a versão do seu arquivo físico. Você pode fazer isso com uma ferramenta como o notepad++, por exemplo, basta alterar o formato do arquivo para UTF-8.